# Django - how to upload to a specific S3 bucket?

Tags: django, django-models, django-storage

I've tried `ImageField(upload_to='', storage=S3MediaStorage)`, it gives an error `TypeError: get_valid_name() missing positional argument: 'name'` when `save()` is called. But if I leave out the `storage=` and leave it to use the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` bucket, it works flawlessly.

`S3MediaStorage`:

```
class S3MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket'] = getattr(settings, 'AWS_BUCKET_MEDIA')
        super(S3MediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', storage=S3MediaStorage)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created)
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a completely different approach to upload the file to a non-default bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `super`:

```
return super(S3MediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```